# Laravel 8 Multiple Pagination in one page with tabs

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

I have one page which has two tabs, each one has it's pagination.
It works correctly only when I click on tab, but when I click on previous or back page, it keeps returning to the first tab.
this is my code on controller:

```
 $entries = Entry::paginate(5,['*'],'entries')
        ->appends(request()->except('entries'));
 $company_responses= CompanyResponse::paginate(5,['*'],'company_responses')
        ->appends(request()->except('company_responses'));
```

on view

```
{{$entries->appends(request()->except('entries'))->links()}}

{{$company_responses->appends(request()->except('company_responses'))->links()}}
```

tabs links

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'tab1')">الملاحظات</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event,'tab2')">القيود</button>
</div>
```

I don't know what I need to do to make it works on previous or back.

Comment: You need to add the tab paramater to your links so that is triggers the correct tab to display when you paginate - your links are currently setup like its just on a page - Laravel needs you to tell it is inside a tab.

Comment: How I can do this???

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Crisha:
Create a separate query for each tab and paginate the results

```
$tab1 = Model::where('column', 'value')->paginate(10);
$tab2 = Model::where('column', 'value')->paginate(15);
```

I think you should be able to use this:

```
{{ $tab1->fragment('tab_id')->links() }}
{{ $tab2->fragment('tab_id')->links() }}
```

That should then add the tab # to the pagination links, you might need to add tab1 & tab2 where is has tab_id - as this is untested.

Comment: I've tried this, it changes the URL, but the paginations still not working.

Comment: Can you comment with what your URL looks like when you click on the pagination in tab2 vs what the url looks like in the browser when you refresh the page and open tab2?

Comment: this URL for clicking on page2 on tab2 but still shows tab1 page1
```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/company_response?entries=2#tab2
```
When re-click on tab2 , and now it show its content
```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/company_response?entries=2#tab2
```
every time I click to show new page from pagination its redirect to tab1, after click on tab2 it show its content.

Comment: I've realised - the issue will be the active class you have on tab1 you need to add another "tab" get variable to your pagination unique to tab1 and one for tab2 then make an if statement to only put active on the tab1 panel if the variable to tab2 isn't present in the page route.

what we have done so far is only going to focus the cursor on the tab - the javascript is choosing to show tab1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I've add this JavaScript function on document ready to hide Tab1, after add fragments to pagination link. and it works fine right now.
```` 
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("tab2") != -1) {
        $("#tab1").hide();
        $("#tab2").show();
    }
});